# Unable to get different pictures of the hangman to show when user enters wrong guess in my hangman game

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When the user types in a letter and it is wrong, the correct image is not popping up. I am able to get the first picture (the gallow) to show up, but other than that it wont change when there is a wrong letter inputted by a user.

I have tried multiple things like import pictures and require but nothing is working. also have tried making the function "updateAttempts()" to just attempts and the same thing is happening.

```
class HangmanPicture extends React.Component {
      updatePicture()
      {
        const image0 = require('./hangman0.png');
        const image1 = require('./hangman1.png');
        const image2 = require('./hangman2.png');
        const image3 = require('./hangman3.png');
        const image4 = require('./hangman4.png');
        const image5 = require('./hangman5.png');
        const image6 = require('./hangman6.png');

          let image = image0;
          if(this.props.updateAttempts === 5)
          image = image1
          else if(this.props.updateAttempts === 4)
          image = image2
          else if(this.props.updateAttempts === 3)
          image = image3
          else if(this.props.updateAttempts === 2)
          image = image4
          else if(this.props.updateAttempts === 1)
          image = image5
          else if(this.props.updateAttempts === 0)
          image = image6

           return (<img src={image} alt="" />)
      }

      render(){

        return(
            <div className="HangmanPicture">
             {this.updatePicture()}
            </div>
        );


      }
    }
```

no error messages it compiles with warnings but other than that it somewhat works

Comment: How are you incrementing `updateAttempts`?

Answer (score 0):

well, in first place, you need to bind updatePicture or to make it an arrow function.

So updatePicture should be:

```
updatePicture = () => {
  ...
}
```

Also, this.props.updateAttemps has to be updated someway. If you dont update any state, how do you think that updateAttemps will change and display the correct image?